# either in a question

Tags: grammar

Is it possible to create a question with "either""

I don't like him. Don't you like him either?
She doesn't work. Don't they work either?

It seems to me weird.

Comment: possibly, your answer is here- http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/27186/can-not-either-be-used-in-a-interrogative-sentence

Comment: "*Really? You don't like either one?!*"

Comment: I just haven't heard anyone using either in questions that's why it's seems a bit strange.

Comment: @Tomek I was trying to give you an example of either in a question ;)

Comment: Yes of course but it's something else. However, I do agree that it's a question but  the meaning, I mean, how the word "either" is used is a different one. Am I right?

Comment: @scohe001: Should I upvote *either or neither* of your comments?

Comment: Ok, I see , It's a question but again it's something else. It's not : I don't like him. Don't you like him either?

Comment: The point that's being made by the examples is that your question is unclear... Presumably you're asking **only** about the specific use in your question... so you might want to make the question a bit more exact...

Comment: Yes absolutely you're right. I'm interested in the above mentioned questions whether it's possible to use "either" in them or not.

Comment: It's very simple to create a question with "either", as all of your teachers or text-books shoud have explianed. Where, plesae, did they let you down?
If you really think that belongs here, rather than for instance at English Language Lerners, can you explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"either" = (any) one of the two; one or the other (of two)

In any appropriate situations, such as in the first pair of your sentences, the question ending with "either" is perfectly normal and common.

I've re-created your scenario here:

You: I don't like him.
Joe: Don't you like him either? - automatically means he too doesn't like him, i.e., neither you nor Joe likes him.

May be that answers your question.

Comment: Perfect answer! That's the point. Exactly the meaning I'm interested in. Fantastic job. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: My pleasure! You can count on us.